# What is the best way of writing a CASE within a CASE for multiple conditions in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I need to write a case within a case statement with 3 conditions.
When A=B
When A>B
when A<B

When I execute my query, I only get results where A=B.

There is Data where A>B and A<B but I am getting getting empty strings.

```
CASE WHEN A = B THEN

CASE WHEN VALUE_In_A IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Do something'

CASE WHEN VALUE_In_B IN (5,6,7) THEN 'Do something'

ELSE

CASE WHEN A > B THEN

CASE WHEN VALUE_In_A IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Do something'

CASE WHEN VALUE_In_A IN (5,5,6) THEN 'Do something'

ELSE

CASE WHEN A < B THEN

CASE WHEN VALUE_In_B IN (1,2,3) THEN 'Do something'

CASE WHEN VALUE_In_B IN (5,5,6) THEN 'Do something'

END END
```

The Exact code is below
The whole purpose here is:
if jdGroupCode = emGradeCode, return emGradeCode
if jdGroupCode > emGradeCode, return emGradeCode
if jdGroupCode < emGradeCode, return jdGroupCode

```
  case when jdGradeCode = emp.emGradeCode 
  then      
  case when emp.emGradeCode in ('1','2','3')    then 'Unskilled'                
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('4','5','6','7')     then 'Semi-Skilled'                          
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('8','9','10','11','12','13')  then 'Junior Management (Sklled & Academically Qual)'                
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('14','15','16','17') then 'Middle Management (Prof Qual)'                
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('18','19','20','21') then 'Senior Management'                
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('22','23','24','25') then 'Top Management' 
  else      
  case when jdGradeCode > emp.emGradeCode     then      
  case when EMP.emGradeCode in ('1','2','3')    then 'Unskilled'     
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('4','5','6','7')     then 'Semi-Skilled'    
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('8','9','10','11','12','13')  then 'Junior Management (Sklled & Academically Qual)'           
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('14','15','16','17') then 'Middle Management (Prof Qual)'      
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('18','19','20','21') then 'Senior Management'    
  when EMP.emGradeCode in ('22','23','24','25') then 'Top Management' 
  else 
    case when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode     then      
  case when jdGradeCode in ('1','2','3')    then 'Unskilled'     
  when jdGradeCode in ('4','5','6','7')     then 'Semi-Skilled'    
  when jdGradeCode in ('8','9','10','11','12','13')  then 'Junior Management (Sklled & Academically Qual)'           
  when jdGradeCode in ('14','15','16','17') then 'Middle Management (Prof Qual)'      
  when jdGradeCode in ('18','19','20','21') then 'Senior Management'    
  when jdGradeCode in ('22','23','24','25') then 'Top Management' 
end end end end end end,
```

Comment: Are `VALUE_In_A` and `VALUE_In_B` other columns in the table or you mean A and B?

Comment: This query doesn't compile - you have 9 instances of `CASE` and only two instances of `END`. Can you post the query you are actually executing that is giving incorrect results rather than pseudo code?

Comment: @GarethD  I have pasted the exact code I executed

Comment: @forpas exact code added

Comment: Your nesting levels are wrong, you basically have `CASE WHEN jdGradeCode = emp.emGradeCode THEN <all your logic> END`. So if this initial condition is not met you will not reach any other part of the case expression. You most like want `CASE WHEN jdGradeCode = emp.emGradeCode THEN ... WHEN jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode THEN ... ELSE ... END`. You'll find using good indentation and making sure your `CASE` aligns with your `END` will really help spot issues like this.

Comment: As an aside are `jdGradeCode` and `emp.emGradeCode` numeric or strings? You are checking if they are strings (e.g. `in ('1', '2', '3')`) but also apply numeric conditions (`jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode`). If they are strings then `>` will yield results you probably don't expect e.g. `'20' < '3' = TRUE`, and if they are numeric then you should compare them to numbers rather than string literals to avoid ay implicit conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the logic you want to apply the main CASE expression needs 3 branches and for each branch another CASE expression:

```
case 
  when jdGradeCode = emp.emGradeCode then   
    case 
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('1','2','3') then 'Unskilled'    
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('4','5','6','7') then 'Semi-Skilled'        
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('8','9','10','11','12','13')  then 'Junior Management (Sklled & Academically Qual)'    
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('14','15','16','17') then 'Middle Management (Prof Qual)'    
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('18','19','20','21') then 'Senior Management'    
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('22','23','24','25') then 'Top Management'    
    end
  when jdGradeCode > emp.emGradeCode  then   
    case 
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('1','2','3') then 'Unskilled'  
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('4','5','6','7')  then 'Semi-Skilled' 
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('8','9','10','11','12','13')  then 'Junior Management (Sklled & Academically Qual)'     
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('14','15','16','17') then 'Middle Management (Prof Qual)'   
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('18','19','20','21') then 'Senior Management' 
      when emp.emGradeCode in ('22','23','24','25') then 'Top Management' 
    end 
  when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode  then   
    case 
      when jdGradeCode in ('1','2','3') then 'Unskilled'  
      when jdGradeCode in ('4','5','6','7')  then 'Semi-Skilled' 
      when jdGradeCode in ('8','9','10','11','12','13')  then 'Junior Management (Sklled & Academically Qual)'     
      when jdGradeCode in ('14','15','16','17') then 'Middle Management (Prof Qual)'   
      when jdGradeCode in ('18','19','20','21') then 'Senior Management' 
      when jdGradeCode in ('22','23','24','25') then 'Top Management' 
    end
end
```

But this way you have to repeat 3 times the same logic.
Unfortunately SQL Server does not support a function like `LEAST()` that other databases like MySql and Postgresql support and would help to shorten/simplify the code.
So, you can use another CASE expression to get the least of `emp.emGradeCode` and `jdGradeCode`:

```
case 
  when case when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode then jdGradeCode else emp.emGradeCode end in ('1','2','3') then 'Unskilled'    
  when case when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode then jdGradeCode else emp.emGradeCode end in ('4','5','6','7') then 'Semi-Skilled'        
  when case when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode then jdGradeCode else emp.emGradeCode end in ('8','9','10','11','12','13')  then 'Junior Management (Sklled & Academically Qual)'    
  when case when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode then jdGradeCode else emp.emGradeCode end in ('14','15','16','17') then 'Middle Management (Prof Qual)'    
  when case when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode then jdGradeCode else emp.emGradeCode end in ('18','19','20','21') then 'Senior Management'    
  when case when jdGradeCode < emp.emGradeCode then jdGradeCode else emp.emGradeCode end in ('22','23','24','25') then 'Top Management'    
end
```

This would also be simplified further, maybe with the use of a subquery, orby using `<` and `>` operators instead of enumerating all the values inside the `in` lists.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks a mill. The end statements caused my proc to return missing strings

Answer (score 0):

I would say your cases are mixed up an missing `END` conditions, this should archive what you want

```
CASE WHEN A = B THEN
    CASE WHEN VALUE_IN_A IN (1,2,3) 
        THEN 'magic string a=b, value in (1,2,3)' 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN VALUE_IN_B IN (5,6,7) THEN 'magic string a=b, value in (5,6,7)' 
            END
        END
ELSE
CASE WHEN A > B THEN
    CASE WHEN Value_IN_A IN (1,2,3) THEN 'magic string a>b value in (1,2,3)' 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN Value_IN_A IN (5,5,6) THEN 'magic string a > b value in (5,5,6)' 
            END
        END
ELSE
CASE WHEN A < B THEN
    CASE WHEN Value_IN_B IN (1,2,3) THEN 'magic string a<b value in (1,2,3)' 
        ELSE 
            CASE WHEN Value_IN_B IN (5,5,6) THEN 'magic string a < b value in (5,5,6)' 
            END
        END
END
END
END
```